# Is there a regex which will generate a String array by splitting a line for the first two spaces (" ") and then adding the rest to one array index?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text file:

```
25678399287 James Hi there!
24467448489 Randy yo, how are you?
36373783388 Fred Ciou amigos!
```

I want to split each line into:
1. the number
2. the name
3. the message.

I have so far been able to split the line into number name and message by using string.split(" "). However this only gets the first word of the message... How do I get the rest of the message?

```
 String line;

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split(" ");
                Arrays.stream(split)
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
                messages.add(new Message(Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseUnsignedLong(split[0])), split[1], split[2]));
```

Current output: 25678399287 James Hi

Comment: Does [`String.split(regex, limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)) help?

Comment: Use `split =line.split(" ", 3);`: up to 1st space goes in `split[0]`, up to second space goes in `split[1]`, rest of line goes in `split[2]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
(\\d+) ([A-Z][a-z]+) (.+)
```

https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a formal regex here, and then repeatedly apply it for each line in your file:

```
String input = "25678399287 James Hi there!\n24467448489 Randy yo, how are you?\n36373783388 Fred Ciou amigos!";
String pattern = "(\\d+) (\\S+) (.*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("number: " + m.group(1) + ", name: " + m.group(2) + ", message: " + m.group(3));
}
```

This prints:

```
number: 25678399287, name: James, message: Hi there!
number: 24467448489, name: Randy, message: Randy yo, how are you?
number: 36373783388, name: Fred, message: Ciou amigos!
```